# Can't parse network_interface_id as a resource id:Cannot parse AzureID:parse module.network.azurerm_network_interface.primary.id: invalidURIforrequest

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-provider-azure

```
on modules/security_group/main.tf line 64, in resource "azurerm_network_interface_security_group_association" "primary":
      64:   resource "azurerm_network_interface_security_group_association" "primary" {
```

I am getting above output with "terraform validate" command
Below are the configuration that i used for terraform.
Here is the tree that I am working as module

```
├── main.tf
    └── modules
        ├── network
        │   ├── main.tf
        │   ├── variable.tf
        │   └── variable.tfvars
        ├── resource
        │   ├── main.tf
        │   ├── variable.tf
        │   └── variable.tfvars
        ├── security_group
        │   ├── main.tf
        │   ├── variable.tf
        │   └── variable.tfvars
        ├── storage
        │   ├── main.tf
        │   ├── variable.tf
        │   └── variable.tfvars
        └── vm
            ├── main.tf
            ├── variable.tf
            └── variable.tfvars
```

main.cf :

```
#Select provider
    provider "azurerm" {
      subscription_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      version = "~> 2.4"
      features {}
    }
  module "resource" {
      source = "./modules/resource"
      resource_group_name = "devops_primary"
      location = "southeastasia"
    }
   module "network" {
      source = "./modules/network"
      virtual_network = "primaryvnet"
      subnet = "primarysubnet"
      address_space = "192.168.0.0/16"
      address_prefix = "192.168.1.0/24"
      public_ip = "backendvmpip"
      location = "southeastasia"
      primary_nic = "backendvmnic"
      primary_ip_conf = "backendvm"
      resource_group_name = "devops_primary"
    }
    module "vm" {
      source = "./modules/vm"
      vm_name = "backendvm-primary"
      vm_size = "standard_d2s_v3"
      vm_storage_od_disk_name = "backend-vm-os-disk-primary"
      computer_name = "backendserver"
      username = "terraform"
      ssh_key_path = "/home/terraform/.ssh/authorized_keys"
      keys_data = "~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
    }
    module "security_group" {
       source = "./modules/security_group"
       sg_group_name = "primary_sg"
       primary_nic_id = ["module.network.primary_nic_id"] 
    }
```

Here is resource's main.cf file:

```
#Select provider
provider "azurerm" {
  subscription_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  version = "~> 2.2"
  features {}
}

#Create Primary Resource Group
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "primary" {
  name     = "var.resource_group_name"
  location = "var.location"
  tags = {
        environment = "Test"
    }
}
output "devops_primary" {
  value = "${azurerm_resource_group.primary.name}"
}
output "location" {
    value = "${azurerm_resource_group.primary.location}"
}
```

Here is network's main.cf file:

```
#Create public IP address
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "primary" {
    name                         = "var.public_ip"
    location                     = "module.resource.azurerm_resource_group.primary.location"
    resource_group_name          = "module.resource.azurerm_resource_group.primary.name"
    allocation_method            = "Dynamic"
    tags = {
        environment = "Test"
    }
}
output "public_ip_id"{
  value = azurerm_public_ip.primary.id
  }
#Create Network Interface
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "primary" {
  name                = "var.primary_nic"
  location            = "module.resource.azurerm_resource_group.primary.location"
  resource_group_name = "module.resource.azurerm_resource_group.primary.name"
   resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  ip_configuration {
        name                           = "var.primary_ip_conf"
       #subnet_id                       = "${azurerm_subnet.primary.id}"
        subnet_id                       = azurerm_subnet.primary.id
        private_ip_address_allocation  = "Dynamic"
        #public_ip_address_id            = "${azurerm_public_ip.primary.id}"
        public_ip_address_id           = azurerm_public_ip.primary.id
        #public_ip_address_allocation   = "Dymanic"
    }
  tags = {
        environment = "Test"
    }
  # depends_on = [var.subnet_id_primary]
    #depends_on                     = [module.resource.azurerm_resource_group.name]
}
output "primary_nic_id"{
  description = "Primary VNET NIC Id "
  value = ["azurerm_network_interface.primary.id"]
  }
output "private_ip" {
  description = "private ip addresses of the vm nics"
  value       = "${azurerm_network_interface.primary.private_ip_address}"
}
```

Here is VM's main.cf file:

```
#Create VM in Primary resource
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "primary" {
  name                  = "var.vm_name"
  location              = "module.resource.azurerm_resource_group.primary.location"
  resource_group_name   = "module.resource.azurerm_resource_group.primary.name"
  vm_size               = "var.vm_size"
  network_interface_ids = ["module.resource.azurerm_network_interface.primary.id"]
  storage_os_disk {
    name              = "var.vm_storage_od_disk_name"
    os_type           = "Linux"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = "Premium_LRS"
  }
storage_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "UbuntuServer"
    sku       = "18.04-LTS"
    version   = "latest"
  }
  os_profile {
    computer_name  = "var.computer_name"
    admin_username = "var.username"
  }
  os_profile_linux_config {
    disable_password_authentication = true
  ssh_keys {
      path     = "/home/terraform/.ssh/authorized_keys"
      key_data = file("~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub")
    }
  }
  tags = {
        environment = "Test"
    }
}
```

Here is security_group's main.cf file:

```
#Create Network Security Group
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "primary" {
    name                = "var.sg_group_name"
    #location            = "module.resource.azurerm_resource_group.primary.location"
    #resource_group_name = "module.resource.azurerm_resource_group.primary.name"
     resource_group_name = "var.resource_group_name"
     location            = "var.location"
    #Security Rules for Security Group
    security_rule {
        name                       = "SSH"
        priority                   = 1001
        direction                  = "Inbound"
        access                     = "Allow"
        protocol                   = "Tcp"
        source_port_range          = "*"
        destination_port_range     = "22"
        source_address_prefix      = "*"
        destination_address_prefix = "*"
    }
    security_rule {
        name                       = "AppOut"
        priority                   = 1002
        direction                  = "Inbound"
        access                     = "Allow"
        protocol                   = "Tcp"
        source_port_range          = "*"
        destination_port_range     = "8040"
        source_address_prefix      = "*"
        destination_address_prefix = "*"
    }
    security_rule {
        name                       = "MySql"
        priority                   = 1003
        direction                  = "Inbound"
        access                     = "Allow"
        protocol                   = "Tcp"
        source_port_range          = "*"
        destination_port_range     = "3306"
        source_address_prefix      = "*"
        destination_address_prefix = "*"
    }
    security_rule {
        name                       = "Redis"
        priority                   = 1004
        direction                  = "Inbound"
        access                     = "Allow"
        protocol                   = "Tcp"
        source_port_range          = "*"
        destination_port_range     = "6379"
        source_address_prefix      = "*"
        destination_address_prefix = "*"
    }
    tags = {
        environment = "Test"
    }
}
variable "primary_nic_id" {}
# Connect the security group to the network interface
  resource "azurerm_network_interface_security_group_association" "primary" {
    #network_interface_id      = "${module.network.azurerm_network_interface.primary.id}"
    network_interface_id      = "module.network.azurerm_network_interface.primary.id"
    network_security_group_id = "${azurerm_network_security_group.primary.id}"
    #depends_on                = ["module.network.primary_nic_id"]
    #primary_nic_id               = ["var.primary_nic_id"]
}
#depends_on                = [module.network.primary_nic_id]
# Generate a new ID only when a new resource group is defined
 resource "random_id" "randomId" {
    keepers = {
        resource_group_name = "module.resource.azurerm_resource_group.primary.name"
    }
    byte_length = 8
}
```

Please review the code I am currently working, I am new to terraform, just started still a learner.

Comment: Remove the quotes around `module.network.azurerm_network_interface.primary.id`

Comment: How can use depends_on output from network module to input to security group module ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you may remove quotes for all non-constant expressions and leave the inner inner expression. To begin upgrading your configuration, run the `terraform 0.12upgrade` commands.

> Terraform 0.11 and earlier required all non-constant expressions to be
>   provided via interpolation syntax, but this pattern is now deprecated.
>   To silence this warning, remove the "${ sequence from the start and
>   the }" sequence from the end of this expression, leaving just the
>   inner expression.
>
> Template interpolation syntax is still used to construct strings from
>   expressions when the template includes multiple interpolation
>   sequences or a mixture of literal strings and interpolations. This
>   deprecation applies only to templates that consist entirely of a
>   single interpolation sequence.

[Calling a Child Module](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/modules.html#calling-a-child-module)

> To call a module means to include the contents of that module into the
>   configuration with specific values for its **input variables**. Modules
>   are called from within other modules using `module` blocks:
>
> ```
> module "servers" {
>   source = "./app-cluster"
>
>   servers = 5
> }
> ```

[Accessing Module Output Values](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/modules.html#accessing-module-output-values)

> The resources defined in a module are **encapsulated**, so the calling
>   module cannot access their attributes directly. However, the child
>   module can declare output values to selectively export certain values
>   to be accessed by the calling module.
>
> For example, if the `./app-cluster` module exported an `output` value named 
>   `instance_ids` then the calling
>   module can reference that result using the expression
>   `module.servers.instance_ids`:
>
> ```
> resource "aws_elb" "example" {
>   # ...
>
>   instances = module.servers.instance_ids
> }
> ```
>
> For more information about referring to named values, see [Expressions](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html).

For example, In this case, you can not query a value from a module as your code

```
network_interface_id      = "module.network.azurerm_network_interface.primary.id"
```

The correct expression is `module.<MODULE NAME>.<OUTPUT NAME>`. It is the value of the specified `output` value from a child module called by the current module. You should query the `azurerm_network_interface.primary.id` from the `network` module like this `network_interface_id = module.network.primary_nic_id`

Also, since the module blocks are declared in the root directory in your code, you can not directly reference them from your child modules configuration files. You can use input variables to pass the value to your child module from root module. See [output values](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/outputs.html).

For example, in the module `network` in the root directory, you call the module `resource` output `devops_primary` from module `network` like this `resource_group_name = module.resource.devops_primary`

```
module "network" {
  source = "./modules/network"
  resource_group_name = module.resource.devops_primary
  location = module.resource.location
  virtual_network = "primaryvnet"
  subnet = "primarysubnet"
  address_space = ["192.168.0.0/16"]
  ...
}
```

in the ./modules.network directory, you have

```
#Create Virtual Network in Primary Resource Group
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "primary" {
  name                = var.virtual_network
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  address_space       = var.address_space
  location            = var.location

}

variable "resource_group_name" {

}

variable "location" {

}
```

You could re-edit your configuration files following the above rules. For more examples, you could search [azurerm modules](https://registry.terraform.io/browse/modules?provider=azurerm).